# Instantiate instance with a callback composed of events

Tags: android, kotlin

I am currently implementing an app that uses a printer from Hoin. They provided an SDK that I can integrate in Android Studio (done) and tell me to instantiate the instance like this:

```
val mHoinPrinter = HoinPrinter.getInstance(context, mode, callback)
```

For context and mode, no biggies. For the callback I am having troubles.
In their documentation they specify that the callback is of interface `PrinterCallback` which is composed like so:

```
Public interface PrinterCallback {
     Public void onState(int state); //state callback, parameter is status code, refer to status code definition
     Public void onError(int errorCode); //Error callback, parameter is error code, refer to error code definition
     Public void onEvent(PrinterEvent event); //Event callback, parameter is PrinterEvent event, refer to PrinterEvent definition
}
```

Which is great because it gives me 4 events that should be triggered at some point.

My issue is that I have no clue how to actually instantiate it. I know that I need to do it like so `val mHoinPrinter = HoinPrinter.getInstance(this.context, 2, callback)` but where I have troubles is in defining the `callback`. Should I write a function? should I setup something extra? How can I define logics for this callback?

It's very confusing when reading the docs online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create an implementation of the `PrinterCallback` `interface` and then pass that implementation as a parameter to `getInstance` method. The implementation can be created as so

```
val callback = object: PrinterCallback{
    override fun onState(state: Int) {
        // DO SOMETHING
    }

    override fun onError(errorCode: Int) {
         // DO SOMETHING
    }

    override fun onEvent(event: Int) {
         // DO SOMETHING
    }
}
```

If you do everything else as specified in the documentation then these three functions will be invoked on their respective events

Comment: Thanks! as a first time kotlin user I was really confused.